# Integral u-substitution of u=$\frac{2x}{1+x^2}$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I was curious about the validity of doing such a substitution in an integral:

(1)$$u=\frac{2x}{1+x^2}$$

Changing this around a bit

$$ux^2 - 2x + u = 0$$

Solving with the quadratic formula

with $a=u, b=-2, c=u$:

$$x=\frac{1 \pm \sqrt{1 - u^2}}{u}$$

I had discerned that both definitions for x (+ and -) are indeed true, plugging this into (1). However, I’m confused as to whether doing this substitution (with the intent to specifically replace parts in the integrand with x, rather than letting the differentials cancel things out) is even valid given there’s two possible definitions for x based on the original statement (1). Even if it is, I’m also not sure about how one would solve for the differentials.

For example, in this problem:

$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x^2}\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\right)dx$$

Comment: It would help to include, in your post, the integral you want to use this substitution in, or the integral question $X$ that led to this question $Y$, so we aren't confronting an X-Y problem.  Note, that if you have the integral $\int \dfrac{2x}{1+x^2}\,dx$, you have essentially $\int \frac{(1+x^2)' dx}{1+x^2} = \ln(1+x^2) + C$.

Comment: The point to observe is that the function $g(x)=\frac{2x}{1+x^2}$ *is* one-to-one on the interval $[0,1]$, so the substitution will be valid when the integration is over $[0,1]$.  But, in fact, integration by substitution is valid even when $g$ is not one-to-one, provided you actually have $\int_a^b f(g(x))g'(x)\,dx$, because this integral *equals* $\int_{g(a)}^{g(b)}  f(u)\,du$.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The two substitutions are both valid. Note the reciprocal relationship between the two choices

$$\frac{1 + \sqrt{1 - u^2}}{u}
=\frac{u}{1- \sqrt{1 - u^2}}$$

to see that they are not equivalent, though, with one being the inverse of the other.

Comment: Did you read the full question??  No you didn't. E.g., what is $du$ in terms of $dx$?  And this doesn't solve the problem the OP was trying to solve in the first place: $$ \int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x^2}\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\right)dx$$

Comment: @amWhy - It is already pointed out in the answer that the two substitutions are not the same and they are inverse of each other, accordingly their $du$. You may not have read the answer carefully

Comment: I read your answer carefully, and yet again, I note that it does not answer the question! $$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x^2}\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\right)dx$$  You're trying to reply to the Y question, which is really based on the $X$ question.  In addition to reading the question, read the comments.

Comment: @amWhy - It’s possible it is just your opinion

Comment: It's more probable you don't know what you are doing, especially as you try to be a FGITW&LHF answerer.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion guys. Sorry, I don’t really think the reciprocal relationship between the two answers my question. I want to know if one could just casually replace x with either the + or - version of $\frac{1 \pm \sqrt{1 - u^2}}{u}$.